# Add severals flashs using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using `request.flash` to send flashs to the users... But I'd like to send severals flahs to a view and `request.flash` seems to not offer this feature.

My code :

```
request.flash('danger', 'some flash in a route');
request.flash('danger', 'some flash in a route 2');
```

Result :

```
some flash in a route 2
```

**Edit #1 (server.js) :**

```
flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add the scope of those request.flash lines? 
the complete function

Comment: I'm using `connect-flash` so I'm not the owner of the module. See edit #1.

Comment: I understand, but I mean the code surrounding this lines:
request.flash('danger', 'some flash in a route');
request.flash('danger', 'some flash in a route 2');

Comment: try to change the first argument of flash function.  
request.flash('danger1', 'some flash in a route');
request.flash('danger2', 'some flash in a route 2');......on and on

Answer (score 0):

from the official documentation

```
// You can add multiple messages
app.get('/add-messages', function (req, res) {
  req.flash('info', 'Flash Message 1 Added');
  req.flash('info', 'Flash Message 2 Added');
  req.flash('info', 'Flash Message 3 Added');
  res.redirect('/');
});
```